# aws ecr get-login-password returns error during connect with Rancher desktop installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rancher

I am trying to configure aws for rancher, but i do get such error

```
C:\Windows\System32>aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> --profile ecrhub | docker login  --username AWS --password-stdin <id>dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/auth": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am using windows command for this and I have Rancher desktop instead of Docker

Comment: Have you tried to run in a Powershell that is running as administrator?

Comment: I am using command promt as admin